# CSS: How to omit the spacing between an h3 and a p element?

Tags: css

I have an h3 element followed by a p element and do NOT want to have a blank line between the h3 and the text in the paragraph.

How do I do so? Thanks. Right now, there's too much space between the heading and the text for my taste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

write this in your css

```
h3, p{
margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the bottom margin of the H3 element (`margin-bottom: 0;`)
 and the top margin of the P element (`margin-top: 0;`).

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of things you have to take a look at, but some of the main things that control spacing are padding and margins. Try setting those to zero:

```
h3,p
{    
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
```

Check your html and make sure there's not an arbitrary  tag lying around too.